# Как на андроид реализовать виджет поверх всех окон?

Tags: виджет, android, java

Добрый день.
Возник вопрос по реализации Андроид виджета который бы располагался поверх всех окон. Т.е. при свертывании моего приложения есть необходимость появления данного виджета, который бы был постоянно на виду. Так вот гуглю пока ничего толком не нашел! Помогите, пожалуйста. Буду рад любой помощи, узнать бы хотя бы в какую сторону копать!

Comment: а при разворачивании чужого приложения? должно быть поверх приложения?

Comment: это стопудово не виджет получится..

Comment: Да должно быть поверх чужого приложения! Так чтобы находясь в любом приложении он был перед глазами!

Comment: И Вы надеетесь, что Ваше приложение будет пользоваться успехом с таким виджетом? Единственное, что у меня в голове сейчас вертится - это Toast. Он может показываться, даже если приложение свёрнуто. Пробуйте наследоваться, ковыряйтесь в исходниках, может у Вас получится создать виджет, который Вам нужен.

Comment: Сделать такое можно, более того, я такое делал. Есть правда несколько ограничений - к примеру, очень тяжело работать с клавиатурой. Делается на базе обычных диалогов, при этом приложение "с низу" доступно. Сорцы дать не могу.

Comment: Может дадите намек или какое нибудь направление? Мне не нужен большой функционал, мне необходимо чтобы после свертывания моего приложения высвечивался виджет с иконкой моего приложения, далее по клику на него открывалось основное меню. Может в оф. документации есть инфа на эту тему?

Comment: Так может "вывесить" Notification - и Вам проще и пользователю мешать не будет

Comment: А как реализовать что то типа виджета внутри своего приложения также поверх остальных активити между которыми я переключаюсь, но так чтобы его можно было перемещать по экрану(опять же все внутри моего приложения)?

Answer (score 2):

Пример картинки поверх всех окон
https://droidqd.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/how-to-make-a-floating-face-bubble-on-home-screen-in-android/

Ключевой кусок

```
 public class FloatingFaceBubbleService extends Service {  
   private WindowManager windowManager;  
   private ImageView floatingFaceBubble;  
   public void onCreate() {  
     super.onCreate();  
     floatingFaceBubble = new ImageView(this);  
     //a face floating bubble as imageView  
     floatingFaceBubble.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating_bubble);   
     windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);  
     //here is all the science of params  
     final LayoutParams myParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(  
       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
       LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,  
       LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,  
       PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);  
     myParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;  
     myParams.x=0;  
     myParams.y=100;  
     // add a floatingfacebubble icon in window  
     windowManager.addView(floatingFaceBubble, myParams);
```

В примере по ссылке можно так же посмотреть реализацию перетаскивания этого окошка пальцем и обработку нажатия (лучше переделать).

Основная идея - отображать view через ViewManager (это можно делать из сторонних классов, но UI потока.)
Чтобы было поверх всех окон - LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE - т.е. вьюшка как во входящем звонке поверх всех окон выскакивает. Только мы ее убирать не будем.
Скорее всего понадобиться еще LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE.

Единственное - это не виджет. Виджет только на рабочем столе. Зато можно рисовать такое окошко из сервиса и постоянно "оживлять" сервис, если его убили.

Comment: Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются на этом ресурсе, так как сторонние ресурсы могут перестать быть активными и тогда ваш ответ перестанет быть полезным для других людей. Более того, это ссылка на англоязычный ресурс. Попробуйте написать развёрнутый ответ на вопрос. Так он поможет большему количеству людей.

Comment: Добавил краткое описание идеи. Далее мне кажется код нагляднее и понятнее. Может его сюда цитировать стоит? -)

Comment: Если он разумного размера, то конечно стоит. Вообще, ответы на этом ресурсе и должны, в основном, содержать код, решающий проблему и пояснения к нему